# Software release lifecycle

Tags: git, release, release-management

Before going into question, I prefer providing the background about the current release strategy. So here it goes:

We use git as version control system.

**Current Process**

1. We release in a monthly sprint.
2. Everybody commits to the master branch only.
3. A code freeze day is fixed well before the release starts.
4. On the day of code freeze master is blocked for new commits and a release candidate is finalized.
5. A new branch is created from the master for that release and say for eg 16.7 (year.month).
6. And finally master is made available for further development.

So now are thinking to move from current process to a new one which will be as follows :

**New Process**

1. There will be 3 releases preview, major, minor.
2. A preview release will be like a internal one where in most of the things that will go in Major release are developed and the release is made available as preview to client.
3. Major release will contain all the fully functional features. And is a production ready.
4. Minor will be a bugfix release for major release.
5. So it will be like a quarterly major release.

**Questions**

1. How will be the branching model for git?
2. Some of the pros and cons with the new process?
3. Any major obstacles that we might face?
4. What should be taken care of to make the transition easy?

I found one link which is kind of suitable for the new process [Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Comment: I think this question belongs on programmer.stackexchange.com , it's not about an actual problem with your code.

Comment: But besides that: what kind of development do you do, why are you not happy with your current process, do you have continuous integration, et cetera. Git is the least relevant part of it, it will do whatever you want.

Comment: Should I ask it over there again or can this question be migrated? @RemcoGerlich

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I didn't get completely by what kind of development you do?  to answer this we have a product which is web based software developed using java technology.

Comment: We use Teamcity as a build server. @RemcoGerlich

Comment: If enough people to vote to migrate it then it will be moved, but I think the question needs to be improved. Right now it's really unclear. Why would it be better to have a quarterly release, why not release every week? We can't tell without knowing more about your work. And if you do explain everything, you probably still know better than we do what your business needs.

Comment: The major reason that I can tell you is, it better suits to our roadmap of major features being released. So that a complete new feature can be made available to the client in a single release and not in chunks. @RemcoGerlich

Answer (score 0):

Why not formalize your workflow in a way that exists and is documented and automated already. Usually you make git do just what you want it to do. So if the pattern you describe is the one that fits your needs, take it. This is a decision of you company that we cannot really help you with a externals.

But if you feel more like a generically more formalized workflow (some would say more restricted) that you do not have to do the documentation for, do some googeling about git patterns, e.g. Gitflow. Maybe this will work better for you.